# how to manipulate position of BufferGeometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, position

I want to rerender 3d model(the local file) using three.js to make it rougher or more exquisite. But how to deal with the BufferGeometry (load with STLLoader.js) to achieve it? Or other attributes need to be handled?

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var material, mesh;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.x = 150;
            camera.position.y = 50;
            camera.position.z = 150;
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            loader.load("sample.stl", function (geometry) {

                var positions = geometry.attributes.position.array;

                // do something with positions

                material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                mesh.scale.set(3, 3, 3);
                scene.add(mesh);
            });

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                       document.getElementById("webgl").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.enableDamping = true;
            controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
            controls.enableZoom = true;
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>


<div id="webgl" style="height: 1000px"></div>
```

Comment: _"to make it rougher or more exquisite"_ It would be great to add explanatory pictures to show what you mean.

Comment: @prisoner849, Rougher one means the model include less vertices, and more exquisite is the opposite. I'm new to three.js, sorry

Comment: You probably mean decimation and subdivision (generic 3D terms). There is the [THREE.SubdivisonModifier](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_modifier_subdivision). You might find something useful [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5806) for decimating.

Comment: @K3N, thanks, I'll check it out.